# how and why Roy's equation works?

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, demand

i know that the roy's identity is: ${\displaystyle x_{i}^{m}(p,w)=-{\frac {\frac {\partial v}{\partial p_{i}}}{\frac {\partial v}{\partial w}}}}$
but i can't understand why it works.
why the fraction between partial derivatives respect to prices and income gives us the marshallian demand curve?

Answer (score 3):

So, the indirect utility is simply ($p$ is a $L\times 1$ vector)

$v(p,w) =  u[x(p,w)]$,

Namely the utility function evaluated at the Marshallian demand.

First, notice that, if $x(p,w)$ (which is a $L\times 1$ vector as well) satisfies the Walras' Law:

$p\cdot x(p,w) = w \ \ \ (1)$

Differentiate this with respect to $w$, we get:

$$ \sum_{l=1}^{L}\frac{\partial x_l(p,w)}{\partial w}p_l = 1 \ \ \ (2) $$

From the UMP, we know that $\partial u[x(p,w)] / \partial x_l = \lambda p_l$, where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier.

Thus

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v(p,w)}{\partial w} &= \sum_{l=1}^{L} \frac{\partial u[x(p,w)]}{\partial x_l(p,w)}\frac{\partial [x_l(p,w)]}{\partial w} \\
&=  \lambda\sum_{l=1}^{L}\frac{\partial [x_l(p,w)]}{\partial w}p_l \\
&= \lambda \ \ \ (3)
\end{align}

The last equality stems from $(2)$

Differentiating the Walras' Law $(1)$ w.r.t. $p_l$ (recall the product rule), we get:

$$ x_l(p,w) + \sum_{k=1}^{L} p_k \frac{\partial x_k(p,w)}{\partial p_l} = 0 \ \ \ (4) $$

Now, differentiate $v(p,w)$ w.r.t. $p_l$:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial v(p,w)}{\partial p_k} &= \sum_{k=1}^{L}\frac{\partial u[x(p,w)]}{\partial x_k(p,w)} \frac{\partial x_k(p,w)}{\partial p_l} \\
&= \lambda \sum_{k=1}^{L} p_k \frac{\partial x_k(p,w)}{\partial p_l} \\
&= -\lambda x_l(p,w)
\end{align}

Et voilà! The Roy's Identity is proven

$$ x_l(p,w) = -\frac{\partial v(p,w)/ \partial p_l}{\partial v(p,w) / \partial w}$$